# Angular2 + Cordova - Cannot match any routes on startup

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I've got a problem with a Angular2 app, when I build it for Android (maybe this problem also occurs on iOS, but I didn't tested it yet). On startup I get the following error message:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: 'android_asset'. Available routes: ['', '/login', '/register', '/lostpw', '/resetpw', '/content'].
```

Due to that the startpage of the app fails to load. To make the app running at all I had to replace the base-tag in the index.html from

```
 <base href="/">
```

to

```
 <base href="file:///android_asset/www/" target="_blank">
```

But as said, now the router tries to resolve android_asset. With in the app I can click on a menu-entry like

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
```

and I am successfully redirected to the home route.

Does anybody know how to solve the problem on the startup?

Version: Angular 2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ZeeshanJan yes setting the href of the base-tag to "." solved the problem

Comment: If I put the base tag as: `<base href="/">` or `<base href=".">` still I face the same issue. do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect to home

`export const StartRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home'
  }
];`

Comment: I have applied this to the app.component.ts but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: this is provideRouter(routes) configuration, check this link http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes  give code snap

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

In home routing module add

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
```

Change `<base>` tag to

```
 <base href="./">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the resolution was to use `'./'` for the base href.  This resolved this issue and several other issues.