# Angular 2 app base href with Cordova IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, angular, angular2-routing

I am developing an application using Angular 2 with cordova. I have used the angular cli to build the appplication. I have now ran into some routing issues on startup when it comes to the IOS application. The base href seems to be set wrong. If I set the base href using: `<base href="/" target="_blank">` the application doesn't load. If the base href is set when I bootstrap the application using: `...,provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue:'/'}), ...` the application will load but I get the following exception:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any
>   routes:
>   'var/containers/Bundle/Application/3C8966ED-7DDD-4309-8C18-10B778C5AE15/test.app/www'

So the application can't function properly since there are critical files that don't get loaded on the start  of the application. For android I encountered the same problem but I found the solution, to set the base href in the following question [android solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881688/angular2-cordova-cannot-match-any-routes-on-startup?rq=1). Have anybody encountered this problem and have a solution?

**Edit:** I solved the problem by using this: `<base href="./" target="_blank">`in index html and remove the `provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue:'/'})`. This way I have to set change the base href depending if I'm deploying the app to android or ios.

Answer (score 7):

I set it as

```
<base href="www">
```

and all css, js and images file loading are correct.